# Chain rule for functions on a complex domain

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Im am confronted with the following claim, which I simply cannot seem to prove:

> Let $s:D\setminus \{0\}\subset \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{R}^n$, let $w(z)=\left(|s_x|^2-|s_y|^2+2i\langle s_x,s_y\rangle \right)$ where  $\langle, \rangle$ is the euclidean inner product on
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then it holds that
>   $$Re(w(z)z^2)=|s_\theta(z)|^2-|z|^2|s_r(z)|^2.$$

where it is implicitly assumed that $r,\theta$ are the usual polar and $|\cdot|$ is here used simultaneously for the complex module and for the norm.

I've tried the following:

\begin{align*}\Re(w(z)z^2) & =\Re\left(\left(|s_x|^2-|s_y|^2+2i\langle s_x,s_y\rangle \right)(x^2-y^2+2ixy)\right) \\
& =\left(|s_x|^2-|s_y|^2\right)(x^2-y^2)-4\langle s_x,s_y\rangle xy.
\end{align*}

On the other hand, using the chain rule, we have that:
\begin{align*}
s_\theta&=s_xx_\theta+s_yy_\theta=s_xy+s_yx\\
s_r& =s_xx_r+s_yy_r=\frac{s_x x+s_y y}{|z|}
\end{align*}
Consequently
\begin{align*}|s_\theta|^2-|z|^2|s_r|^2& =|s_x|^2y^2-2\langle s_x,s_y \rangle xy+ |s_y|^2x^2-|s_x|^2x^2-2\langle s_x,s_y \rangle xy- |s_y|^2y^2 \\
& =|s_x|^2(y^2-x^2)+|s_y|^2(-y^2+x^2)-4\langle s_x,s_y \rangle xy\\
& =(|s_x|^2-|s_y|^2)(y^2-x^2)-4\langle s_x,s_y \rangle xy.
\end{align*}

But confronting the two sides, there appears to be a mistake in my calculation. I am aware that I did the calculation as I had been in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but taking into account the "complex" variable made the the result inconsistent.

Can someone help me out with this issue?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think OPs calculation is correct and the claim is wrong. Let's make a plausibility check with a simple example:

> We set
>   \begin{align*}
>  &s:D\setminus \{0\}\subset \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{R}\\
>  &s(z)=s(x+iy)=x
> \end{align*}
>
> and we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> w(z)&=\left(|s_x|^2-|s_y|^2+2i\langle s_x,s_y \rangle\right)\\
> &=\left(1-0+2i\langle 1,0\rangle\right)\\
> &=1
> \end{align*}
>   It follows
>   \begin{align*}
> \Re(w(z)z^2)=\Re(z^2)=x^2-y^2\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

on the other hand, since
\begin{align*}
x&=x(r,\theta)=r\cdot\cos \theta\\
y&=y(r,\theta)=r\cdot\sin \theta
\end{align*}
with
\begin{align*}
s(z)&=x=r\\
\end{align*}
we get
\begin{align*}
s_\theta&=s_xx_\theta+s_yy_\theta\\
&=s_x\cdot 0+0\\
&=0\\
s_r&=s_xx_r+s_yy_r\\
&=s_x\\
&=1
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \left|s_\theta\right|^2-\left| z\right|^2\left|s_r\right|^2
> =-|z|^2=-x^2+y^2\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> with (2) differing from (1) by a factor $-1$ in accordance with OPs calculation.

Comment: Thank you @Markus. Do you think that it might be possible that I've misinterpreted some notation (like some $|\cdot |$ or inner product) or would you rather say that it is really a typo? One could potentially fix it by writing the equality:
$$-Re(w(z)\overline{z^2})=-Re(\overline{w(z)}z^2)=\left|s_\theta\right|^2-\left| z\right|^2\left|s_r\right|^2$$

Comment: @b00nheT: You're welcome! I think your interpretation is quite ok. It rather seems to be a typo.

Comment: Alright! I'll let you know if one can save the result the paper claims albeit the typo

Comment: @b00nheT: Fine, thanks!